# No implementation found with android chromeview

Tags: android, google-chrome, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run chromeview and when I call `ChromeView.initialize` an `UnsatsifiedLinkError` exception is thrown.

```
12-31 16:16:28.050: D/dalvikvm(4910): Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-31 16:16:28.155: I/LibraryLoader(4910): loading: webviewchromium
12-31 16:16:28.155: D/dalvikvm(4910): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.chromeviewtest-1/libwebviewchromium.so 0x41c443c0
12-31 16:16:28.155: D/dalvikvm(4910): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.chromeviewtest-1/libwebviewchromium.so 0x41c443c0
12-31 16:16:28.155: I/LibraryLoader(4910): loaded: webviewchromium
12-31 16:16:28.155: W/dalvikvm(4910): No implementation found for native Lorg/chromium/content/app/LibraryLoader;.nativeLibraryLoaded:([Ljava/lang/String;)I
12-31 16:16:28.155: D/AndroidRuntime(4910): Shutting down VM
12-31 16:16:28.155: W/dalvikvm(4910): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41995c50)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910): Process: com.example.chromeviewtest, PID: 4910
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.chromium.content.app.LibraryLoader.nativeLibraryLoaded:([Ljava/lang/String;)I
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.content.app.LibraryLoader.nativeLibraryLoaded(Native Method)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.content.app.LibraryLoader.initializeAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:122)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.content.app.LibraryLoader.ensureInitialized(LibraryLoader.java:63)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess$1.run(AwBrowserProcess.java:50)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThreadBlocking(ThreadUtils.java:28)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.start(AwBrowserProcess.java:46)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at us.costan.chrome.impl.ChromeInitializer.initialize(ChromeInitializer.java:49)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at us.costan.chrome.ChromeView.initialize(ChromeView.java:851)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at com.example.chromeviewtest.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:10)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
12-31 16:16:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(4910):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4396)
```

These are the steps I did:

- Add chromeview as an eclipse project
- Created a new android app, chromeviewtest
- Added chromeview as a library
- Copied the pak file to assets/
- Added an Application class like in the README

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that chromeview doesn't work on Android 4.4.

Comment: Since `WebView` is backed by Chromium on Android 4.4, perhaps you can use `ChromeView` just on earlier OS versions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I thought about making different apks for 4.4 and earlier OS versions (since adding chromeview is 30mb+)